# Call a Stored Procedure in MySQL from Batch

Tags: mysql, windows

i want call a Stored Procedure in MySQL from a Windows CMD:
Test.cmd =
call mysql.exe -u xxxxxx --password=xxxxxxxx -h localhost -D tracer -e=tracer.tab_counter_long()

The Stored Procedure looks like:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `TAB_Counter_long`()
BEGIN
declare zahl_al int;
declare zahl_cv int;
declare zahl_ev int;
declare zahl_fa int;
declare zahl_ge int;
declare zahl_pv int;
declare zahl_sp int;
declare ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

Select Count(*) From tracer.css_ket_al into zahl_al;
Select Count(*) From tracer.css_ket_cv into zahl_cv;
Select Count(*) From tracer.css_ket_ev into zahl_ev;
Select Count(*) From tracer.css_ket_fa into zahl_fa;
Select Count(*) From tracer.css_ket_ge into zahl_ge;
Select Count(*) From tracer.css_ket_pv into zahl_pv;
Select Count(*) From tracer.css_ket_sp into zahl_sp;
Delete From tracer.tab_count;
REPLACE INTO tab_count VALUES ( ts, zahl_al, zahl_cv, zahl_ev, zahl_fa, zahl_ge, zahl_pv, 
zahl_sp );
END
```

If i start the command file, i got the Errormessage:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>call mysql.exe -u xxxxxx --password=
xxxxxxxx -h localhost -D tracer -e=tracer.tab_counter_long()
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ma
nual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use n
ear '=tracer.tab_counter_long()' at line 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Perhaps anybody can help me.
Best regards and thanks
Herbert

Answer (score 0):

Your `-E` parameter to the `mysql.exe` command is wrong:

```
mysql.exe <other parameters> -E "CALL TAB_Counter_long"
```